# What is the type of an rvalue reference parameter inside a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have a really simple function definition here:

```
void testRvalue(int&& r)
{
    printf("rvalue ref is called\n");
    testRvalue(r); // this line gives "no known conversion from 'int' to 'int &&' for 1st argument"
}
```

I mean inside this function, what is the type of `r`? Isn't it `int&&` (the parameter is `int&& r` so how come `r` is not of type `int&&`?) If so why can't I pass this `r` to this function itself, which takes a `int&&` type as parameter?

What is the type of `r` exactly? `int&&` or `int`? If `int`, why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A very good read is [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

Yes, the type of the variable `r` is indeed `int&&`. However what matters here is **the expression** and:

> Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, a
> variable name, etc.) is characterized by two independent properties: a
> type and a value category. **Each expression has some non-reference
> type**, and each expression belongs to exactly one of the three
> primary value categories: prvalue, xvalue, and lvalue.

The expression `r` is an lvalue:

> #### lvalue
>
> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable [...], regardless of type. Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its
>   name is an lvalue expression;

Rvalue references can bind to prvalues or xvalue but not to lvalues so if you want to bind an rvalue reference to `r` you need to convert `r` to an xvalue. This is done with [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) which despite its name is just an cast.

You can easily reason about this like so: if it has a name then it's an lvalue (even if the type of that id is rvalue reference). You can't bind rvalue references (which in principle should bind to temporary objects) to something that has a name. Something that has a name can be reused. You need `std::move` to *enable move* from that lvalue.

Regarding the message which says "no known conversion from 'int'". As shown above the type of the expression `r` is `int`, however a more appropriate diagnostic message would have been something along the lines: "rvalue reference cannot bind to lvalue".

And indeed newer clang and gcc give better messages:

gcc

> error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'

clang

> candidate function not viable: expects an rvalue for 1st argument

Comment: It took me a while to realize the whole thing evolved around _expressions_, not variables.